# How are the classes in the Sketch example AppKit application separated into Models/Views/Controllers?

Tags: cocoa, model-view-controller, macos

I am a little confused as to the definition of classes as Models or Views in the Sketch example AppKit application (found at /Developer/Examples/AppKit/Sketch). The classes SKTRectangle, SKTCircle etc. are considered Model classes but they have drawing code.

I am under the impression that Models should be free of any view/drawing code.

Can someone clarify this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The developer of Sketch outlines his/her rationale a bit in the ReadMe file:

---

**Model-View-Controller Design**

The Model layer of Sketch is mainly the SKTGraphic class and its subclasses.  A Sketch Document is made up of a list of SKTGraphics.  SKTGraphics are mainly data-bearing classes.  Each graphic keeps all the information required to represent whatever kind of graphic it is.  The SKTGraphic class defines a set of primitive methods for modifying a graphic and some of the subclasses add new primitives of their own.  The SKTGraphic class also defines some extended methods for modifying a graphic which are implemented in terms of the primitives.

*The SKTGraphic class defines a set of methods that allow it to draw itself.  While this may not strictly seem like it should be part of the model, keep in mind that what we are modelling is a collection of visual objects.  Even though a SKTGraphic knows how to render itself within a view, it is not a view itself.*

---

I don't know if that is a satisfying answer for you or not.  My personal experience with MVC is that while separation of model, view and controller is a "good thing" oftentimes in practice the lines between layers become blurred.  I think compromises of design are frequently made for convenience.

For Sketch in particular, it makes sense to me that the model knows how to draw itself inside a view.  The alternative to having each SKTGraphic subclass knowing how to draw itself would be to have a view class with knowledge of each SKTGraphic subclass and how to render it.  In this case, adding a new SKTGraphic subclass would require editing the view class (adding a new clause to an if/else or switch statement, likely).  WIth the current design, an SKTGraphic subclass can be added with no changes required to the view classes to get things working.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not aware of the particular example that you're refering to, but here's my guess on the reason for that design:

Perhaps the **Models (the SKTRectangle, SKTCircle that you mention) know enough to draw themselves** but not enough to actually perform the drawing to the screen. The drawing to the screen is handled by the View, where **the View will call the Models to find out how to draw them on the screen**.

By taking this approach, the View won't have to know how to draw every single Model that it may encounter -- **the View only needs to know how to ask the Model to draw itself on the screen**.

I'm thinking that it's a trade-off between the MVC model and the object-oriented programming model -- strictly separating along the line of MVC will mean that the View will become extremely large and not very flexible when it comes to adding support for other Models that need to be displayed. With object-orientated design, we'd want the Models themselves to be able to be able to draw themselves on the screen, and we'd want the View to be able to handle new types of Models through facilities such as interfaces.